# Python - Converting time format 12:00a to 24hour

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, time

I have a number of times stored in an array that I need to convert to 24hr time.

[' 06:00a-11:00a', ' 07:00p-11:00p', ' 09:00a-04:00p', ' 09:00a-04:00p', ' 10:00a-04:00p', ' 10:00a-03:00p']

I can't use  %r since the notation is not it "am" or "pm".

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what `%r` means. But you could replace all `'a'` with `'am'` and all `'p'` with `'pm'` in your strings and use "`%r`".

Answer (score 2):

You just need to append an `'m'` to each time and the `strptime` will parse it.

### Oneliner

```
list(map(lambda s: datetime.strptime(s+'m', '%I:%M%p'), s) for s in (s.strip().split('-') for s in l)
```

Output (*redacted for clarity*):

```
[[datetime(…, 06, 0), datetime(…, 11, 0)],
 [datetime(…, 19, 0), datetime(…, 23, 0)],
 [datetime(…, 09, 0), datetime(…, 16, 0)],
 [datetime(…, 09, 0), datetime(…, 16, 0)],
 [datetime(…, 10, 0), datetime(…, 16, 0)],
 [datetime(…, 10, 0), datetime(…, 15, 0)]]
```

### Readable

```
def parse(times):
    split_times = (s.strip().split('-') for s in times)
    parsed_times = []
    for time_group in split_times:
        parsed_group = []
        for time_str in time_group:
            parsed_time = datetime.strptime(time_str + 'm', '%I:%M%p')
            parsed_group.append(parsed_time)
        parsed_times.append(parsed_group)
    return parsed_times
```

Comment: Nice elegant solution.  I tried this in my notebook and needed to modify to `datetime.datetime.strptime` to get it working.  Was this just a typo or is it due to Python versions? I tested with 2.7.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, you need this import: `from datetime import datetime` . You are free to use the `import datetime` and declare the full namespace though, I just preferred to keep it short for the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky, but basically, you can take each string and examine the last character. If it's an `a`, just discard it. If it's a `p`, add 12 to the number before the colon:

```
def translate_times(s):
    # Remove space at the begining and split according to the -
    each = s[1:].split('-')
    for i in range(len(each)):
        if each[i][5] == 'a':
            each[i] = each[i][0:5]
        else:
            each[i] = str(int(each[i][0:2]) + 12) + ':' + each[i][3:5]

    return '-'.join(each)

orig = [' 06:00a-11:00a', ' 07:00p-11:00p', ' 09:00a-04:00p', ' 09:00a-04:00p', ' 10:00a-04:00p', ' 10:00a-03:00p']
result = [translate_times(x) for x in orig]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the quickest solution, but gives the output you requested:

```
 old = [' 06:00a-11:00a', ' 07:00p-11:00p', ' 09:00a-04:00p', ' 09:00a-04:00p', ' 10:00a-04:00p', ' 10:00a-03:00p']

import time
```

Fix am/pm issue:

```
am = list(map(lambda x:x.replace('a','am'),old))
pm = list(map(lambda x:x.replace('p','pm'),am))
```

Remove whitespace and split on '-' character:

```
times = [i.strip() for i in pm];times = [i.split('-') for i in times]
```

List comprehension to return converted times to requested format:

[i+'-'+j for i,j in zip(timelist[::2], timelist[1::2])]

```
['6:00-11:00',
 '19:00-23:00',
 '9:00-16:00',
 '9:00-16:00',
 '10:00-16:00',
 '10:00-15:00']
```